# upload with apache inside a datatable

Tags: java

I have a simple jsf page with a h:datatable holding a list of values.

For every value I have to export a file or import a file.

But when I use t:inputFileUpload inside a h:column the command button never gets the file, is always null. Putting the t:inputFileUpload outside the datatable works, but inside, I cannot do it.

Is there a way to do this? Have another h:column with a t:inputFileUpload inside it?

This is the code:

```
<h:form id="strategiesForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" styleClass="jsfcrud_list_form">
<h:dataTable value="#{strategy.strategyItems}" var="item" border="0" cellpadding="2" 
                             cellspacing="0" rowClasses="jsfcrud_odd_row,jsfcrud_even_row" rules="all"
                             style="border:solid 1px">
                    <f:facet name="header">
                            <h:outputText escape="false" value="Importación"/>
                        </f:facet>
                        <h:panelGrid columns="1" border="0">
                        <h:outputText value="Actualizar formulario"/>
                        <t:inputFileUpload id="file" value="#{strategy.xmlFormFile}"/>
                        <h:commandButton value="Actualizar" action="#{strategy.importForm}">
                        </h:commandButton>
                        </h:panelGrid>
                    </h:column>
</h:dataTable>
        </h:form>
```

In the above code, strategy.xmlFormFile is the property that ALWAYS is null when submitted; if I close the form and write another one with that t:inputFileUpload it works, but I have to discriminate what rows the user wants to import a file into.